# extern global variable issue only in CentOS/RHEL 7

Tags: c++, centos7

I'm trying to debug a troublesome issue. I have a program that is compiled with g++, and it makes use of a global struct that contains some config information.

In most linux/unix environments where this runs, it works fine. But in CentOS/RHEL 7 environments, it looks like we have two different instances of what is supposed to be a global variable. (Note, I'm using generic variable names here)

That global struct is defined with extern in a header file, this way...

```
extern struct collect_config configstruct;
```

and it is initialized in the file with the main function, this way...

```
struct collect_config configstruct = {{0}};
```

Here I'm printing out the pointer address of this global struct in the file where the main function is, and inside a function that is populating the config information. The pointer address is different within this function, as opposed to what it is out with the main function.

```
main A:3417 configstruct address is 0x6c8460
my_config A:952 configstruct address is 0x6c8400
my_config B:957 configstruct address is 0x6c8400
main B:3421 configstruct address is 0x6c8460
```

In any other linux/unix environment, these addresses are the same... (this was taken from a run in Ubuntu 20)

```
main A:3417 configstruct address is 0x6bb500
my_config A:952 configstruct address is 0x6bb500
my_config B:957 configstruct address is 0x6bb500
main B:3421 configstruct address is 0x6bb500
```

I do not see any other places where configstruct is declared/defined.

Any suggestions on what I can look at to try and find out why I'm ending up with two different pointer addresses for what is supposed to be a global variable? (And why this seems to be a problem only in CentOS/RHEL?) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is likely due to symbol visibility, which controls the scope of symbols within the same executable and shared libraries. In C++, symbols are by default hidden, which means they can only be accessed within the same module (i.e. translation unit) they are defined in. The issue you're encountering could be because your program is compiled with different visibility flags in different environments, leading to the same symbol being defined as hidden in one environment and as global in another.

Try compiling your program with the -fvisibility=default flag. This flag sets the visibility of symbols to default, which makes them globally accessible. If this resolves the issue, it means that symbol visibility was indeed the root cause.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, it was a good one... however, it didn't seem to fix this particular issue... after adding that flag, I still saw two different pointer addresses for my global struct in a CentOS 7 enviroment...